# Extensão de função no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, funções

Estou usando o `Laravel 5.3` e aparentemente tenho um `Controller` chamando a função:

```
(new AnuncioRepository())->getListagemAnuncios()
```

e o SQL referente a isso é:

```
return DB::select('
            SELECT
                anuncio.id,
                cliente.nome AS "cliente",
                anuncio_area.nome AS "area",
                DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.data_inicio, "%d/%m/%Y") AS "inicio",
                DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.data_fim, "%d/%m/%Y") AS "fim",
                CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.hora_exibicao_inicio,"%H:%i"),
                    " - ",DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.hora_exibicao_fim,"%H:%i")) AS "horario",
                anuncio.valor,
                anuncio.ativo
            FROM
                anuncio
                RIGHT JOIN anuncio_area ON (anuncio_area.id = anuncio.id_anuncio_area)
                RIGHT JOIN cliente ON (cliente.id = anuncio.id_cliente)
            WHERE anuncio.ativo != "x"
                  AND anuncio.deleted_at is null
            ORDER BY anuncio.id DESC
        ');
```

O que eu queria fazer era estender uma função de contador no `repository` por ***exemplo***:

```
(new AnuncioRepository())->getListagemAnuncios()->count();
```

E ele contasse os registros que o `SQL` retornou, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Se fizeres `DB::select('
            SELECT
               ...
        ')->count();` ele não retorna o número de linhas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a `classe` [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) da seguinte forma:

```
$result = DB::select('
            SELECT
                anuncio.id,
                cliente.nome AS "cliente",
                anuncio_area.nome AS "area",
                DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.data_inicio, "%d/%m/%Y") AS "inicio",
                DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.data_fim, "%d/%m/%Y") AS "fim",
                CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.hora_exibicao_inicio,"%H:%i"),
                  " - ",DATE_FORMAT(anuncio.hora_exibicao_fim,"%H:%i")) AS "horario",
                anuncio.valor,
                anuncio.ativo
            FROM
                anuncio
                RIGHT JOIN anuncio_area ON (anuncio_area.id = anuncio.id_anuncio_area)
                RIGHT JOIN cliente ON (cliente.id = anuncio.id_cliente)
            WHERE anuncio.ativo != "x"
                  AND anuncio.deleted_at is null
            ORDER BY anuncio.id DESC
        ');

return collection($result);
```

com esse ajuste tem objeto da classe [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections) com os métodos implementados, por exemplo o método [count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count). Nesse [link está a relação de métodos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods) que pode ser utilizado. Para mostrar agora todos os registro utilize [all()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-all).

***Como usar:***

```
$result = (new AnuncioRepository())->getListagemAnuncios();
$result->count(); //quantidade de registros retornados
$result->all(); //os registros
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections)
- [Collection - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods)
- [Collection - Available Methods - count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count)
- [Collection - Available Methods - all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-all)

Comment: Muito obrigado! dúvida respondida