# como faço para montar um select com dois campos usando colletivehtml no laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-collective

Boa tarde.

Eu uso o laravel 5.5 e para formulários eu uso o laravelcollective.
Eu monto um select desta forma:
`$locals = Local::get()->pluck('codigolocal', 'id');`
e o resultado é um select com o `value = id` e descrição igual ao código.

Meu problema é que preciso mostrar além do código, também a descrição:
Algo como `$locals = Local::get()->pluck(['codigolocal','descricaolocal'], 'id');`

Tem como fazer isto?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual é o banco?

Comment: Uso o mysql 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça com o comando [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) do MySQL para unir os campos e com o método [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects) do [Builder Eloquent](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) para escrever um `select` igual a esse:

```
Local::selectRaw("id‚CONCAT(codigolocal,' ',descricaolocal) as n")->pluck('n','id');
```

<sub>***Outros exemplos:***</sub>

- [Extensão de função no laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175096/extens%C3%A3o-de-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-laravel/175100#175100)
- [Concatenar campos em uma string](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/265908-concatenar-campos-em-uma-string/)
- [UTILIZANDO CONCAT NO MYSQL](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/10/concat-no-mysql/)

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [12.5 String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Comment: Veja: Não funcionou:

Comment: Controller:         {$locals             = Local::selectRaw('id‚CONCAT(codigolocal," ",descricaolocal) as n')->pluck('n','id');
        $fornecedor         = Fornecedor::get()->pluck('descricao', 'id');
        $fabricante         = Fabricante::get()->pluck('descricao', 'id');
        
        return view('admin.equipamento.create-edit', compact('titulo', 'centrocustos', 'tipoequipamentos', 
                'tipogas', 'locals', 'fornecedor', 'fabricante'));}

Comment: E chamo a view
{        <div class="form-group">
            Selecione o Local
            {!! Form::select('local_id', $locals, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>}

Comment: Coloque todo o `controller` na pergunta! e também qual **a mensagem do problema**, isso é pra funcionar sim @MarcosBirro

Comment: **Qual é a mensagem de erro** @MarcosBirro **e o que não funcionou**

Comment: Ok. MAS FUNCIONOU OK. Fiz uma alteração aqui e funcionou. Obrigado.